# ng-repeat hide rows with empty object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-hide

I have a table where I am repeating over an array of objects. Within the object, there is a nested object, like so:

```
[
    {"Object1": 
         {"Sub_obj" : {}
         }
     },

    {"Object2": 
         {"Sub_obj" : 
               {"Name" : "Jane"}
         }
     }
]
```

I want to `ng-hide` the table row where `"Sub_obj"` is empty. How can I achieve this? I tried `ng-hide=!Sub_obj`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Provide you html with `ng-repeate` please

Comment: Could you please provide the code where you create the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a simple function that checks the length of the keys in object:

```
$scope.isEmptyObject(obj){
  return !angular.isObject(obj) || !Object.keys(obj).length
}
```

view

```
ng-hide="isEmptyObject(item.Sub_obj)"
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-hide="Sub_obj.Name == null  ;

OR ng-hide="Sub_obj.Name == ""